# Filling a List with Objects in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm trying to make a simple program with GUI in c# but unfortunately I have some difficulties. Now I'll try to explain the basic structure of my program. I have 3 classes for three different groups of people(University Professors, University Students and people who don't work or study either). I have some methods for reading information from a file(professor's title, name, university name, student's faculty number, etc.). I read the file line by line and save the information in an object of type one of the 3 classes. After that I put that object in a List. So here comes my problem. I want to read every object from the list and take its name and put in on a dynamically created labels on other windows form. Here it is a little part of my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ForeignPeople fPeople = new ForeignPeople();
        UniversityProfessors uProf = new UniversityProfessors();
        UniversityStudents uStudents = new UniversityStudents();
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            objList1 = loadList();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            for (int i = 0; i < objList1.Count; i++)
            {
                if (objList1[i] is UniversityStudents)
                {
                    uStudents = (UniversityStudents)objList1[i];
                    tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
                    Label et_tag = new Label();
                    et_tag.Name = "label" + i.ToString();
                    et_tag.Text = uStudents.getFirstName().ToString() + " " + uStudents.getLastName().ToString();
                    et_tag.AutoSize = true;
                    f2.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(et_tag, 0, i);
                    Label op = new Label();
                    op.AutoSize = true;
                    op.Text = "description";
                    f2.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(op, 1, i);
                }
                else if (objList1[i] is UniversityProfessors)
                {
                    uProf = (UniversityProfessors)objList1[i];
                    tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
                    Label et_tag = new Label();
                    Label label = new Label();
                    et_tag.Name = "label" + i.ToString();
                    et_tag.Text = uProf.getFirstName().ToString() + " " + uProf.getLastName().ToString();
                    et_tag.AutoSize = true;
                    f2.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(et_tag, 0, i);
                    Label op = new Label();
                    op.AutoSize = true;
                    op.Text = "description";
                    f2.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(op, 1, i);
                }
                else if (objList1[i] is ForeignPeople)
                {
                    fPeople = (ForeignPeople)objList1[i];
                    String name, Name;
                    tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
                    Label et_tag = new Label();
                    et_tag.Name = "label" + i.ToString();
                    et_tag.Text = fPeople.getFirstName().ToString() + " " + fPeople.getLastName().ToString();;
                    et_tag.AutoSize = true;
                    f2.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(et_tag, 0, i);
                    Label op = new Label();
                    op.AutoSize = true;
                    op.Text = "description";
                    f2.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(op, 1, i);
                }

            }
            f2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(childFormClosed);
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
}
```

But if I have two or more lines which belongs to one Object(for example I have two or more students, or two or more professors in the file) the text of all the labels becomes with the name of the last read object. I know that the problem is in the List or in the cast which I make but I can't figure out another way of doing what I want. I'll be extremely grateful if someone can help.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your three classes should inherit from a common base class.  Common logic (first name, last name, description) should be defined in that base class.  Then you wouldn't need the type testing, since the three type-specific blocks of code are identical.

Comment: In my program the UniversityProfessors inherits FreignPeople and UniversityStudents inherits UniversityProfessors. FreignPeople has fields first name and last name, UniversityProfessors adds to this university name and a title(phd, assistent, etc.) and UniversityStudents adds faculty number. So I want to know where is the problem with the code above, is the cast not correct or it's something else.

Comment: Yes it's kind of homework, but I don't see what is the problem... I hope that the code is not so bad(haha). So you can help, I would be very happy.

Comment: The problem: you are violating the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle. Consider: `foreach (var x in collection) if (x is Student) Console.WriteLine(((Student)x).getFirstName()); else if (x is Prof) Console.WriteLine(((Prof)x).getFirstName());`  If Student inherits from Prof, you can just write this: `foreach (Prof x in collection) Console.WriteLine(x.getFirstName());` Simpler in every way.  Finally, inheritance is supposed to model the "is a" relationship.  Students aren't professors, so a common abstract Person base class would be better.

Comment: I assume Student inherits from Professor because they have some common university-related properties, like `UniversityID`.  But Professor could have a Title property that Students would not have.  To handle university-related properties, I would do this: `abstract class Person {} class ForeignPerson : Person {} abstract class UniversityPerson : Person {} class Student : UniversityPerson {} class Professor : UniversityPerson {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the change that phoog mentioned in the comments, I would also move the instantiation of your "people" objects down into the section for each within the loop. That way you can be sure that the old one is being properly destroyed. I would also add a check to make sure that the cast worked.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        objList1 = loadList();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();

        for (int i = 0; i < objList1.Count; i++)
        {
            if (objList1[i] is UniversityStudents)
            {
                UniversityStudents uStudents = (UniversityStudents)objList1[i];

                if (uStudents != null)
                {
                    // do stuff
                }
                else
                {
                    // do something sensible with the error here
                }
            }
            // if clauses for the other "people" objects
            // ...
        }
        f2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(childFormClosed);
        f2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, but the result is the same, all the labels get the name of the last read object.

Comment: @user1860311 That's odd. Are you sure you're storing the objects correctly in the first place? Perhaps there's a bug in your code that pulls the data from the file and assigns it to the objects.

Comment: There is a chance the code not being stored correctly. The objects in the objList1 are from type Object. Then how you can see i check every object if it's instance of UniversityStudents, UniversityProfessors or ForeignPeople and after that cast it to one of the classes. I thought that is correct but if not correct me.

Comment: @user1860311 Honestly, I'm not sure if your object model really makes sense. Since each person is different from one another and not really a subset of each, it makes more sense to have them derive from a single point. I would be inclined to define a single `Person` class and then derive each of the three classes from that one. You can still see which class you're dealing with per object and then cast it. However that aside, I think your basic premise of casting to the desired object is OK, you just need to debug a bit further and double check that the right data is going to the right place.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the model really does't make sense but I'm still learning programming and from time to time I make mistakes. In that case I gave the students Title "Student", as I think in that case it would be easier for me. Finally I can say that I found where the problem in my program was. I created an object which was defined out of the method where it is used. So it was never destructed, and the whole List was full of the same object. Thanks for all your help, you all help me a lot to find that glitch.